# np.average not working when data is missing when using pandas groupby

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, weighted-average

I'm getting stuck at computing weighted averages with pandas groupby and numpy's np.average. The problem seems to be the missings in the data (that is missings; in the *data*, not in the *weigths*). I made a conceptual example below.

The behaviour that I'd like to have is that when data is missing, the weight of that record is also ignored. Simply deleting the row is not an option because other data-columns are filled with data. I thought np.ma.average is just what I need, but that also gives me NaN as a result.

Any suggestions?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'groups': ['a','a','b','a','b','b'],
                    'data':  [3, 3, 4, 2, 2.5, np.nan],
                    'Weights': [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3]})

def wavg(subdf):
    series = pd.Series()
    for column in df.columns:
        series['np.mean'] = np.mean(subdf['data'])
        series['np.average (no weights)'] = np.average(subdf['data'])
        series['np.average (weighted)'] = np.average(subdf['data'], weights=subdf['Weights'])
        series['np.ma.average (weighted)'] = np.ma.average(subdf['data'], weights=subdf['Weights']) 
    return series

df.groupby('groups').apply(wavg)
```

This gives me

```
       np.mean  np.average  np.average  np.ma.average 
               (no weights)  (weighted)    (weighted)
groups              
a    2.666667    2.666667    2.5              2.5
b    3.250000    NaN         NaN          NaN
```

====================================
For the curious, this is what I ended up using:

```
def wavg(subdf):
    series = pd.Series()
    for column  in columns:
        df = subdf.dropna(subset=[column])
        if len(df) == 0:
            series[str(column)] = np.nan
        else:
            series[str(column)] = np.average( df[column], weights=df['Weights'])

    return series
```

Comment: Can you just compute the average on `subdf['data'].dropna()`?

Comment: nope, I need a weighted average and if I do a dropna() I get: Length of weights not compatible with...

Comment: Why do you have that loop in your `wavg`?  It doesn't seem like you want to do anything per column; you're only computing *one* set of averages for each entire group, not one per column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `np.average` doesn't handle `nan` itself, you'll have to handle them yourself.  The easiest way to do this is to just subset your `subdf` before doing anything on it.  Add `subdf = subdf.dropna(subset=['data'])` at the beginning of your `wavg` to get rid of rows that have NaN in the "data" column:

```
def wavg(subdf):
    series = pd.Series()
    subdf = subdf.dropna(subset=['data'])

    series['np.mean'] = np.mean(subdf['data'])
    series['np.average (no weights)'] = np.average(subdf['data'])
    series['np.average (weighted)'] = np.average(subdf['data'], weights=subdf['Weights'])
    series['np.ma.average (weighted)'] = np.ma.average(subdf['data'], weights=subdf['Weights']) 

    return series
```

As I suggested in my comment, I removed the loop from `wavg`.  You only want to return one set of averages (i.e., one mean, one average, one weighted average, one masked average) per group.  But with your loop, you are recomputing this same thing four times for every group (since there are four columns in your DataFrame).

Comment: Thanks! The reason for the loop was that I want to compute averages on all the columns in my original dataframe.